# A Lebesgue integration problem

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Hello everyone here is an exercice left without correction that I'm struggling with .

$(E,\mathbb{A},\mu)$ is a **measurable space**

We define :

> $\varphi : E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+ $

as a positive measurable function

and the application *$\nu$* definite over $\mathbb{A}$ by :

> $$\forall A \in \mathbb{A} \;|\; \nu(A) = \int \varphi 1_Ad\mu$$

( some trouble with latex and the indicator function )

I proved that $\nu $ is a measure on $(E,\mathbb{A})$

*1) Given h a non-negative measurable fuction defined on $E$ prove that :*

> $$\int hd\nu = \int h\varphi d\mu$$

And that

> **$h$** is integrable over **$\nu$** if and only if **$\,h\varphi$** is integrable over **$\mu$**

2) Now we suppose that $(E,\mathbb{A},\mu)= (\mathbb{R},B(\mathbb{R}),\lambda )\;\;  $(Borel set) and we define :

> $\varphi (x) = e^{-x}1_{[0,+\infty[}(x)$

Here too I proved that **$\nu$** is a probability measure

We  introduce : $\,h_1(x)=x \; \; $ and $h_2(x)=x^{2}$

And now we have to calculate :

> $$\int h_1d\nu \;\;\;and\;\;\; \int h_2d\nu$$

3) Now we introduce : $\, h_t(x)=e^{tx}$

I found that for $t$<$1\;$ $h_t$ is Lebesgue integrable , but stuck to calculate :

> $$\int h_td\nu$$

I hope everything is clear thanks in advance for your help .

Edit : I'm new here is anything wrong with my question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that
$$
\begin{align*}
\int h_t\,\mathrm d \nu &=\int h_t\varphi \,\mathrm d \lambda \\
&=\int\mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty )}(x) e^{tx}e^{-x}\,\mathrm d \lambda (x)\\
&=\int_{[0,\infty )} e^{(t-1)x}\,\mathrm d \lambda (x)\\
&\overset{(*)}{=}\int_0^\infty e^{(t-1)x}\,\mathrm d x\\
&=\frac1{t-1}(\lim_{x\to \infty }e^{(t-1)x}-e^{(t-1)0})\\
&=\frac1{t-1}(\lim_{x\to \infty }e^{(t-1)x}-1)
\end{align*}
$$
where in $(*)$ we used the equivalence of the integral w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure of Riemann-integrable non-negative functions and the improper integral of Riemann, what you can easily prove that it holds using, by example, the monotone convergence theorem.

Thus for $t< 1$ we have that $\int h_t\,\mathrm d \nu =\frac1{1-t}$.

Comment: Thanks @Masacroso , have you an answer for the 1) please ?

Comment: @Simba27 I thought that you were asking just for the last statement. The equivalence on 1) is almost immediate using simple functions

Comment: No actually I was asking for $\;\int h_2 d\nu\;$ also and the question 1)  if it does not bother you

Comment: @Simba27 try to answer it yourself, I already know the answer. If I solve it for you then you will not learn something. Follow my previous hint to prove it, that I will clarify a bit now: sure you knows that $h=h^+-h^-$ and that there is an increasing sequence of simple function that converge pointwise to $h^+$, and other increasing sequence that converge to $h^-$. Then using that and the monotone convergence theorem the identity on 1) is very easy to prove

Comment: well, in your case is simpler because $h$ is non-negative and so $h=h^+$, so there is an increasing sequence of simple functions that converge pointwise to $h$. With this sequence and the monotone convergence theorem the proof is almost immediate

Comment: Alright thanks , and any hint for $\int h_2d\nu$ , you're right it's more clear using beppo-levi for 1)

Comment: for $h_2$ just use what I had done in the answer, just substitute $h_t$ by $h_2$ and proceed in the same way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101769/discussion-between-simba27-and-masacroso).